# Freeing any dynamically allocated memory associated with a list and returning NULL?

Tags: c, memory, dynamic, free, allocation

```
typedef struct ArrayList
{
    // We will store an array of strings (i.e., an array of char arrays)
    char **array;

    // Size of list (i.e., number of elements that have been added to the array)
    int size;

    // Length of the array (i.e., the array's current maximum capacity)
    int capacity;

} ArrayList;
```

I have this function, which uses the above struct to dynamically allocate memory for an array of strings:

```
ArrayList *createArrayList(int length){


ArrayList *n = malloc(sizeof(ArrayList));


int initial = 0, i;
n->size = initial;


if (length > DEFAULT_INIT_LEN)
{

n->array = malloc(length * sizeof(char*));
n->capacity = length;

if (n->array == NULL)
    panic("ERROR: out of memory in Mylist!\n");

for (i = 0; i< n->capacity; i++)
{
    n->array[i] = NULL;
}

}
else
{
n->array = malloc(DEFAULT_INIT_LEN * sizeof(char*));
n->capacity = DEFAULT_INIT_LEN;

if (n->array == NULL)
    panic("ERROR: out of memory in Mylist!\n");

for (i = 0; i< n->capacity; i++)
{
    n->array[i] = NULL;
}

}

printf("-> Created new ArrayList of size %d\n", n->capacity);


return n;

}
```

My problem is every time I try to call this function in main my program crashes:

```
ArrayList *destroyArrayList(ArrayList *list)
{


    free(list);


    return NULL;

}
```

How can I correctly implement a destroyArrayList function that frees any memory allocated by the createArrayList function without crashing my program?

Comment: Crashes how?  That code looks fine (except for the memory leaks).

Comment: When I call the function in main, my program works fine until the point where destroyArrayList is called and then it crashes. Also, what memory leaks do you see?

Comment: Your create function calls `malloc` twice, but the destroy function only calls `free` once.  Do you get an error message with your crash?  What does the debugger say?

Comment: I'm getting a Segmentation fault, what do you suggest?

Comment: I suggest that the pointer you're passing to the destroy function isn't what you think it is.  I don't have any context here to help you more than that, though.

Comment: I added a define for your `DEFAULT_INIT_LEN` and replaced panic with printf. In the main function I create one list with your create function and then free that list with your destroy function. There are some memory leaks, but no segfault. Is there more code? Can you please post your main?
EDIT: You can fix the remaining memory leaks by addind `free(list->array);` to your destroy method right before `free(list);`

Comment: Well I forgot to mention that the struct is contained in a header file which also defined DEFUALT_INIT_LEN. The main calls many other functions which are complete and working, I've only posted these two because i'm having trouble freeing what createArrayList allocated.

Comment: I honestly cannot reproduce the problem and after adding that `free(list->array);` statement, valgrind reports no memory leaks. There must be something else going on :)

Comment: Please edit your post to includes the un-posted code for part of the issue is there.  Other shortcoming are pointed about already by others.  Questionable is you never do anything with `.size`.  Also destroyArrayList() should free the `char *` pointers as well as the `char **` pointers mentioned above.  I suspect your problem lies in 1) how you use create/use/free your char * pointers or 2) if you are using any of your main's `ArrayList *` variable after you free it.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
static ArrayList *n = malloc(sizeof(ArrayList));
```

instead of

```
ArrayList *n = malloc(sizeof(ArrayList));
```